# error message using RBloomberg

Tags: r, com, finance, bloomberg

I am testing RBloomberg to access the Bloomberg API. Upon creating a connection using

```
> conn <- blpConnect()
```

I receive a pop-up error message stating that "The program can't start because XLCall32.dll is missing from your computer."

However, XLCall32 is in the proper Office subdirectory.

The error is actually generated by the assignment within the function

```
conn <- COMCreate("Bloomberg.Data.1")
```

This is a warning message: if one clicks OK, the API seems to work fine.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there an easy fix? Alternatively, is it possible to suppress the pop up window in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible can you upgrade to the Java-based version available from http://findata.org/rbloomberg

The COM-based version is no longer being developed (I will be removing it from CRAN soon).

Answer (score 1):

Try `system("path")` to see if that directory is known to R.

Comment: It produces no output. Unlike when I do it from the command line

Comment: I can see the path. I added the directory where XLCall32 is. Restarted R and tried again. Same behavior.

Comment: If you can't beat'em, join'em.  Copy the damn dll into your current working directory, the R binary directory, the system32 path, ... you name it.  You analysed the issue ("missing dll"), it ain't that hard to address it.  Apart from the pain that working on Windows imposes on your soul, of course.

Comment: I'll try. my workstation has all sorts of strange constraints. I can't copy files in half the directories. Crzye... thanks.