# Missing XLCALL32.DLL in blpConnect() call (R)

Tags: r, bloomberg

I just installed RBloomberg and when I call `blpConnect()` it returns an error saying *"This application has failed to start because XLCall32.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."*

So, until here, re installing has been done three times including once through `(install.packages("RBloomberg",repos="http://r.findata.org/"))` and no change

I added the dll in R's path using `Sys.setenv(PATH=..)` and still the same error. Any idea on that issue?

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5185213/602276

Comment: i saw this link, didn't  solve my problem. If you notice I did the same things that was advised on this link, downloading the java version and adding the dll to the path, still stuck

Comment: XLCALL32.DLL is a dynamic library from EXCEL, so there's apparently something fishy about your Office installation. I would be highly surprised if that library could not be found if you're on a Bloomberg workstation with a correct installation of Office. You might want to try the sig-finance mailinglist, as the RBloomberg guys reside there : https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance

Comment: ok doing it, if any return I'll post it here

Comment: Did you also install the v3 Bloomberg API? It's required for the Java-based version of RBloomberg at findata.org.

Comment: Hi Michael, I just installed v3 Bloomberg API through WAPI and reinstalled R and RBloomberg package but still the same error message. Im trying the R sig finance mailing list following Joris Meys advice now.

Comment: Ok now it´s working. I added the dll again to the R´s path with Sys.setenv(PATH=...) and that time it worked. I was probably wrong the first time I tried but the point is the solution lied in the PATH environment variable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Whomever stumbles here. I had the same problem. I used Bloomberg Excel API diagnostics to find problems and do a repair. Once done, this issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

this dll is a part of ms office - locating it under office installation folder and copying to C:\blp\API\Office Tools folder worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just not in the path - I copied to C:\WINDOWS